# What does while (cin >> ch) mean?

Tags: c++

```
unsigned int aCnt=0, eCnt=0, iCnt=0, oCnt=0, uCnt=0;
char ch;
while (std::cin >> ch)
    switch (ch){
        case 'a':
            ++aCnt;
            break;
        case 'e':
            ++eCnt;
            break;
        case 'i':
            ++iCnt;
            break;
        case 'o':
            ++oCnt;
            break;
        case 'u':
            ++uCnt;
            break;
    }
```

What does `while (std::cin >> ch)` mean? I entered a letter and the program showed nothing.

Comment: What did you expect it to show and why?

Comment: This code shouldn't show anything, independent from what you enter.

Answer (score 0):

This is bad style code.
It will work and count all characters in switch.
Here is my version, that will help you to understand:

```
unsigned int aCnt = 0, eCnt = 0, iCnt = 0, oCnt = 0, uCnt = 0;
char ch;
while (std::cin >> ch)
{
    switch (ch) {
    case 'a':
        ++aCnt;
        break;
    case 'e':
        ++eCnt;
        break;
    case 'i':
        ++iCnt;
        break;
    case 'o':
        ++oCnt;
        break;
    case 'u':
        ++uCnt;
        break;
    case '-':
        goto end;
    }
}
end:
cout << aCnt << "\t" << eCnt << "\t" << iCnt << "\t" << oCnt << "\t" << uCnt;
```

So put '-' and then Enter to see results.

Here is more common way to do this

```
unsigned int aCnt =0, eCnt = 0, iCnt = 0, oCnt = 0, uCnt = 0;
char ch;
bool getCharacter = true;
while (getCharacter)
{
    std::cin >> ch;
    switch (ch) {
    case 'a':
        ++aCnt;
        break;
    case 'e':
        ++eCnt;
        break;
    case 'i':
        ++iCnt;
        break;
    case 'o':
        ++oCnt;
        break;
    case 'u':
        ++uCnt;
        break;
    case '-':
        getCharacter = false;
        break;
    }
}
cout << aCnt << "\t" << eCnt << "\t" << iCnt << "\t" << oCnt << "\t" << uCnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

`cin>>ch` means you input something to variable `ch`.
`while(cin>>ch)` means loop to execute the input.
There is no `cout`, so you can't watch anything.

You can add some code like:

```
switch (ch){
    case 'a':
        ++aCnt;
        cout<<aCnt<<endl;//added
        break;
    case 'e':
        ++eCnt;
        cout<<eCnt<<endl;//added
        break;
    case 'i':
        ++iCnt;
        cout<<iCnt<<endl;//added
        break;
    case 'o':
        ++oCnt;
        cout<<oCnt<<endl;//added
        break;
    case 'u':
        ++uCnt;
        cout<<uCnt<<endl;//added
        break;
}
```

You should see the number every time when you input one of 'a,e,i,o,u'